# How to get data from different api on particular list item position

Tags: android

Not able to get different API data on listview different item clicks

```
ApiAllEmailInterface apiInterface = (ApiAllEmailInterface) ApiEmailClient.getApi();

Call<EmailModel> call = apiInterface.getResult(email);
call.enqueue(new Callback<EmailModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<EmailModel> call, Response<EmailModel> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d("result", "onResponse: " + response.body());
        Log.d("result1", "onResponse1: " + response);
        EmailModel model = response.body();

        List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(model.getContents().size());
        String[] passwords = new String[model.getContents().size()];
        for(int i=0;i<model.getContents().size();i++) {
            passwords[i]=model.getContents().get(i).getPassword();
            listContents.add(passwords[i]);
        }

        lvone.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_items, listContents)));
        lvone.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String value = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                MainActivity ma = null;
                ma.hitApi();
            }
        });
```

In `onItemClick`, how to use API response which is in my `MainActivity` class as it's my Login class and on different password, my home screen but now how to get that login API hit response in listview at particular item click?

Comment: Are you aware that you're setting MainActivity ma to null, and then you call ma.hitApi() on a null reference?

Comment: @just_user What should I change n this which I am unaware. I got exception

Comment: Is this code already in your MainActivity? If so, just call hitApi(); if not, then just pass MainActivity to the class you are calling this from.